# Vim not showing messages for less than 3 occurrences substitutions

Tags: vim, macvim

Lets say

Text1 has 4 lines

`1
2
1
1`

After `:%s/1/A/g`, Vim will give message says  `3 substitutions on 3 lines`

Text2 has 3 lines

`1
2
1`

`:%s/1/A/g` There are no messages showing.

I typed ":messages" nothing in the history either, so I wonder if there's a way to tell the vim to give message no matter the number of occurrences. Thanks.

BTW, here's my [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/ldong/87787109d876fdb9ef89)

### Update

Like Christian Brabandt said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606894/2305243)

by adding `set report=0` to my vimrc fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `'report'` option. Set it to zero, if you always want a message.